# WPF Nested List performance Problems

Tags: wpf

The below code has performance issues with second combo box... when I change first combox and then open second combox it is good. But if I change the first combox for second time and try to open the 
second combox box it has lot of performance issues....

public partial class MainWindow :  Window, 
INotifyPropertyChanged
 {

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Books = new List<Book>();
        Books.Add(new Book("Abc"));
        Books.Add(new Book("Cde"));
        Books.Add(new Book("Xyz"));
        Books.Add(new Book("Min"));
        this.DataContext = this;
        SelectedBook = Books[0];
    }

    Book _selctedBook;
    public Book SelectedBook
    {
        get { return _selctedBook; }
        set
        {
            _selctedBook = value;
            raiseChange("SelectedBook");
        }
    }

    List<Book> _books = new List<Book>();
    public List<Book> Books { get { return _books; } set { _books = value; raiseChange("Books"); } }

    void raiseChange(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

}

public class Book : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<BookType> BookTypes { get; set; }

    BookType _selectedBookType;
    public BookType SelectedBookType { get { return _selectedBookType; } set { _selectedBookType = value; raiseChange("SelectedBookType"); } }

    public Book(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        BookTypes = new ObservableCollection<BookType>();


        if (name == "Abc")
            BookTypes.Add(BookType.Action);

        BookTypes.Add(BookType.Comedy);
        BookTypes.Add(BookType.Drama);
        BookTypes.Add(BookType.Friction);
        BookTypes.Add(BookType.Thriller);

        SelectedBookType = BookTypes[0];
    }


      void raiseChange(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

public enum BookType
{
    Friction,
    Drama,
    Action,
    Thriller,
    Comedy,
}

<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate2">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding .}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ComboBox Height="23" Name="comboBox1"   Grid.Row="0"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBook,Mode=TwoWay}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Books}" 
              DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
               Width="386" />
    <ComboBox Height="23"  Name="comboBox2" Grid.Row="1" DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=comboBox1}" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding BookTypes}"  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBookType,Mode=TwoWay}" 
               Width="386" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource ItemTemplate2}">

    </ComboBox>

</Grid>
```

Comment: +1 for a question with some good example code, however your example code works just fine on my machine without any performance issues at all.

Comment: run the application , change the combox 1 item to say xyz.open combox box 2. Now change the combox 1 again to say Abc and try opening the combox 2 ... notice a great lag before the dropdown opens

Comment: It works just fine for me. Perhaps there's something different in our environment? I'm using VS2010 Ultimate, .Net Framework 4.0, and Windows XP SP3.

Comment: Is it the actual code or you have stripped unnecessary code which might be real problem like accessing any resource like network, database or any file?

Comment: I checked the code and the example you made has no performance issues. That can only mean that you have not made a correct abstraction of your own code. I agree with Akash that possibly the dataretrieval is to blame and you have bypassed that in your example.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it has to do with rebindthing the second enum every time the first box changes.

Instead, bind the second box once;

```
        <Grid.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate2">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding .}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>

            <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="BookTypeEnum" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type System:Enum}">
                <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                    <x:Type TypeName="local:BookType"/>
                </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            </ObjectDataProvider>

        </Grid.Resources>


  <ComboBox Height="23"  Name="comboBox2" Grid.Row="1" DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=comboBox1}" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource BookTypeEnum}}"  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBookType,Mode=TwoWay}" 
           Width="386" />
```

Comment: But combox2 items change with a change in combox box item 1... for example ABC has action type

Comment: ok, see that now - you are using enums as flags - so instead of a collection, set one value with (flagged) enum values - bookTypes= A+B+D; and display it with checkboxes or something. why would you use a combobox in this manner? BTW - my answer handled your performance problem, didnt solve your logic approach.

Comment: what I am saying is BookType depends on the book. So some books cann't have booktype action available to them. so As I change the book I need the Booktype options to change.

Comment: I will not disagree there is a performance issue, that should not be, in the way you are using it, for such a small example. but I suspect it is not in your code, but WPF. I doubt if this use case was given much weight in design and testing. A enum flag approach would still work if it becomes an issue in real-life. As @rachel indicated, it is barely detectable on my machine.

Comment: This is not actual business scenario... inorder to make it simple I modified the code to book an dbooktypes.  I am using windows 7 and vs ultimate. on my machine it takes good 2 sconds to open the drop down..should I post it on microsoft forums ?

Comment: @charvind Do you get your items for your 2nd combobox dynamically as needed? Or are they pre-loaded like your sample?

Comment: To those who do not see a performance problem, what are your numbers? what machines are you running on, have you even considered how a lower speed machine would run or is your answer to throw more hardware at it? I don't mind being told I am wrong on something I do not know about, but for somebody (with a decent reputation) to come along and say there is no performance problem, after I have indicated I also see it, well I take it personally. So, back up your   claims, let's see your numbers. Or are you just guessing?